# simple algorithm for checkinf if A* is valid

Tags: algorithm

Let A be some set of strings
Let A* be a string made of the combination of elements in A

what is a simple algorithm to check if A* is made of element of A

ex

A = {a,b,c,de}

A* = acbbde

how to check that  A* is valid?

Comment: Write a FSA - pick the language

Comment: `"acbbde" =~ /^(a|b|c|de)*$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways. Let `n` be the size of (longer) string in characters. here few examples:

**a) if by elements you mean characters (`A={a,b,c,d,e}` not `A={a,b,c,de}` )**

1. **sort `A,A*` ascending**

   this can be done in `O(n.log(n))` or if you use bucket sort then in `O(n)`.
2. **test if all characters of `A*` are in `A`**

   this can be done with simple for with two indexes in `O(n)` something like this:

   ```
   char A[]="abcde\0",B[]="abbcde\0"; // input
   for (int a=0,b=0,ret=0;(A[a])&&(B[b]);) // loop through both A,A*
    {
    while((A[a]<B[b])&&(A[a])) a++; // step in A
    if (A[a]!=B[b]) { ret=0; break; } // A* is not made from A
    else ret=1;                       // A* is made from A 
    b++;
    }
   // here ret holds the result
   ```

   the C++ code is untested (just so you see what I mean). If the `A` or `A*` is empty the result `ret` will be `false` so if you need `true` handle that case by initializing `ret=1`.

**b) histogram**

1. **do ordered histograms for `A,A*`**

   saturate the counts to 1. So the probabilities will be only `0` or `1`;
2. **compare histograms**

   in similar way as in **a) #2**

**c) brute force**

Simply for each element in `A*` search if such element is present in `A`. This leads to 2 nested loops `O(n^2)` or if `m` is the size of `A` then `O(n.m)`

**[Notes]**

If the elements of `A` are strings then you need to sort them by the size descending. Then first search the longest strings, and shortest last otherwise you could mis match something. Also you could run into problems if some elements are prefix of other element. If you want to use `a),b)` in such case then you need to reindex the `A*` to characters in this way. (substitute elements by their index in `A`)